# how to create radio button in a table column Python QT

Tags: python, qt

Here is my code:

```
for row in range(rows):                   
    item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(self.vector[row ][column])
    if self.vector[row ][column]=='':
          item.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable |
                              QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
          item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)                 

    self.table.setItem(row, column, item)
```

Now this code is creating check boxes inside a table column. How to create a radio button instead.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Create a subclass of a QStyledItemDelegate and attach it to your view